# edit value in session

Tags: php, html

**Scenario :**

I have an simple php form to calculate things and calculate prices.

Now im stuck at my edit function.

- I have a simple switch `switch ($_GET['actie'])`  with cases like add , edit and delete.
- This is my session : `$_SESSION['data'][] = $_POST;`

**Edit Case :**

```
if (isset($_POST['submitnieuw'])) 

    $data['lengtezijde'][$_GET['key']]  = $_POST['nieuw'];
    Laden(0);
```

**Edit Form:**

```
else

        echo $_GET['key'];
        <form action="index.php?actie=wijzigen" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nieuw">
        <input type="submit" name="submitnieuw" value="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="ky" value="$_GET['key;]"> 
        </form>


    break;>
```

i can see the key of the value i want to edit but it wont edit the `$data['lengtezijde']` value

if some things are missing or my question is unclear let me know.

Comment: We have no idea what `$_GET['key']` contains. Can you show the output of `var_dump($data)` and `var_dump($_GET['key'])`?

Comment: @loko print_r $data = ( [hoogte] => 1 [kleur] => 1 [lengtezijde] => 233 [toevoegen] => toevoegen )

Comment: @Loko var dump key just adds NULL after the array

Comment: @johannes So yeah your $_GET['key'] is not set. I'd assume you want the hidden field you have in your form so you'd need: `$_POST['ky']` + there is a typo in your value: `<input type="hidden" name="ky" value="$_GET['key;]"> ` should be `<input type="hidden" name="ky" value="$_GET['key']"> ` I also see you mix html with php while not using php tags or echoing the html which would cause errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your edit case you are using the GET value of the key, but from your form it looks like you should be using a POST value here instead. Try changing this:

```
$data['lengtezijde'][$_GET['key']]  = $_POST['nieuw'];
```

To this:

```
$data['lengtezijde'][$_POST['ky']]  = $_POST['nieuw'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser but I tried that before but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you done a print_r($data) after setting the value as in my example above? Also, is the goal to change the value in the session? If so, are you making that change to the session later on? Have you tried doing it immediately like this:
$_SESSION['data']['lengtezijde'][$_POST['ky']] = $_POST['nieuw'];

Comment: if i use your code and than do print_r $data it shows : `lengtezijde] => Array ( [$_GET['key']] => new value )`

Comment: my goal is to edit a posted value that is already in the session

Comment: if i try it immidiately like you said it only shows "lengtezijde"